# How to solve ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined this error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular8

Hi i need to remove multiple files uploaded from an array based on user selection in javascript or angular.........
I have tried with below code

First we have a files that are uploaded in an array and is displayed in checkboxes as shown below in code

```
   <div *ngFor="let image of uploadedImages" style="margin-left:10%"  >
          <label class="container" style="font-size:14px">
            {{image.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;ModifiedDate:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{image.lastModifiedDate}}
            <input type="checkbox" style="float:left" value="{{image.name}}" id="lifecheck"
                   [name]="image.name">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="checkmark"></span> <br><br>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-left:34px;padding-bottom:3px;">
          <button *ngIf="imagefilename.length" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:200px;padding-left:30px" (click)="dropzone.reset();resetimage(image.Checked)">
            Reset Selected files
          </button>
        </div>
```

The user will click on the checkboxes that are to be removed and the click on the button displayed and

it calls a function as displayed below

```
resetimage(imageName:any) {
 for(var index = 0; index<this.uploadedImages.length;index++){
 if(document.getElementByName("lifecheck")[i].checked==true){
 this.uploadedImages.splice(index,1);
}
}
}
```

So in this function ,only first file in an array is getting removed where the user has selected multiple files to remove

So please help me if there is any solution

Expected result :
to remove multiple files uploaded from an array based on user selection in javascript or angular

Actual result :
Getting error

Answer (score 0):

In your typescript `document.getElementByName("lifecheck")` cannot find the element in the dom hence you getting the error. In your dom you are creating dynamic input elements with id ='lifecheck'. This is already the wrong way of assigning ids, since dom ids must be unique.

So to fix this you can change your view to assign dynamic unique ids to your input elements:

```
   <div *ngFor="let image of uploadedImages;let i=index" style="margin-left:10%"  >
          <label class="container" style="font-size:14px">
            {{image.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;ModifiedDate:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{image.lastModifiedDate}}
            <input type="checkbox" style="float:left" value="{{image.name}}" id="lifecheck_{{i}}"
                   [name]="image.name">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="checkmark"></span> <br><br>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-left:34px;padding-bottom:3px;">
          <button *ngIf="imagefilename.length" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:200px;padding-left:30px" (click)="dropzone.reset();resetimage(image.Checked,i)">
            Reset Selected files
          </button>
```

So you are creating input elements with id= "lifecheck_1" etc. Then you can pass this id to your typescript function and find the element:

```
resetimage(imageName:any,id:number) {
 for(var index = 0; index<this.uploadedImages.length;index++){
 if(document.getElementById("lifecheck_" + id).checked==true){
 this.uploadedImages.splice(index,1);
}
}
}
```

**NOTE: this should be the way to fix your error;**

Comment: Hi JustLearning Thanks for the quick response but still its not working throwing the same error

Comment: add console.log(id) in resetimage method. What value do you see there. Inspect your html and see if you can find checkbox with id =lifecheck_id

Comment: Also note that i changed your button click event assignment to resetimage(image.Checked,i)